Error logs filling up with Client AH02027/AH2026: Failed to release SSL session cache lock
My error_log is filling up with tons of entries like:
www.mine.com [Sun Dec 29 09:29:59 2024] [warn] [pid 903933] ssl_engine_mutex.c(105): (22)Invalid argument: [client AH02027: Failed to release SSL session cache lock
www.mine.com [Sun Dec 29 09:30:00 2024] [warn] [pid 1177911] ssl_engine_mutex.c(92): (22)Invalid argument: [client AH02026: Failed to acquire SSL session cache lock
www.mine.com [Sun Dec 29 09:30:00 2024] [warn] [pid 1177911] ssl_engine_mutex.c(105): (22)Invalid argument: [client AH02027: Failed to release SSL session cache lock
www.mine.com [Sun Dec 29 09:30:00 2024] [warn] [pid 1177911] ssl_engine_mutex.c(92): (22)Invalid argument: [client AH02026: Failed to acquire SSL session cache lock
www.mine.com [Sun Dec 29 09:30:00 2024] [warn] [pid 1177911] ssl_engine_mutex.c(105): (22)Invalid argument: [client AH02027: Failed to release SSL session cache lock

The host solved it at first with:

I've set the following option in your MySQL configuration file:
log_warnings                  = 0
This will prevent the logging of warnings, but won't interfere with
normal error logging.

But after another MySQL upgrade they now say:

This should be resolved now. The problem was the old setting used to
suppress these of "log_warnings" was deprecated in 5.7 and removed in
mySQL 8.0. I have updated the configuration file with the new mySQL
directive below.
log_error_verbosity = 1
This will result in the same behavior of warnings being suppressed and
only actual errors will be logged going forward.

It didn't work so they replied back:

Our lead sysadmin has looked into this and unfortunately could not
find a way to suppress those warnings, so I'm afraid those are
"normal" for all intents and purposes.

They provided some additional information:

The only mutex value set in any of the active Apache configuration
files is the following:
Mutex default:/usr/nobody
'DUMP_RUN_CFG' returns these mutex values:
Mutex default: dir="/usr/nobody" mechanism=default   Mutex
ssl-cache: using_defaults   Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults   Mutex
authdigest-opaque: using_defaults   Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults   Mutex authdigest-client:
using_defaults   Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults   Mutex proxy:
using_defaults
There had been a reported bug that caused this error in much earlier
versions of Ubuntu + Apache, such as:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1565744
but in those cases the mutex mechanism returned by 'DUMP_RUN_CFG' was:
mechanism=fcntl
and we haven't been able to find anything relevant to the version of
Apache running on your server (2.4.62).

Does anyone know how to stop all this logging, it makes it hard to find actual things in error_log that need to be looked at.
TIA!!
